# Как запустить бинарную программы?

Tags: golang, ос

Как запустить .exe программу средствами Golang? Программа должна запуститься в новом окне `main.exe` (В программе действует поток ввода/вывода, считывание данных с клавиатуры)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    output, err := exec.Command("main.exe").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
}
```

Запускаю, ничего не появляется, в диспетчере задач появляется `main.exe`, но она бездействует, потому что как я сказал выше она считывает данные и потом уже действует. Если я перепишу `main.exe` без считывания данных с клавиатуры тогда программа запустится и всё прекрасно выведется на экран. Как сделать так чтоб программы который считывали данные с клавиатуры нормально выполнялись/работали?

Comment: "в новом окне" имеется ввиду окно cmd.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял для запуска в новом окне нужно всего лишь добавить аргумент **start**:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "start", "main.exe")
cmd.Start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Обычно программа наследует стандартный ввод от той, которая её запустила, то есть ввод нужно производить в текущем окне. Но в Golang exec.Cmd по-умолчанию [ввод переопределяется на нулевое устройство](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd):

```
    // Stdin specifies the process's standard input.
    //
    // If Stdin is nil, the process reads from the null device (os.DevNull).
    //
    // If Stdin is an *os.File, the process's standard input is connected
    // directly to that file.
    //
    // Otherwise, during the execution of the command a separate
    // goroutine reads from Stdin and delivers that data to the command
    // over a pipe. In this case, Wait does not complete until the goroutine
    // stops copying, either because it has reached the end of Stdin
    // (EOF or a read error) or because writing to the pipe returned an error.
```

Можно переопределить его обратно:

```
cmd := exec.Command("main.exe")
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
```

Если нужно отдельное окно - можно запустить отдельный cmd.exe:

```
exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", "main.exe")
```

Comment: Не знаю почему, может это я что-то не то сделал, но этот способ не сработал. Но когда я добавил аргумент `start` у меня прекрасно запустилась программа в новом окне :)